# How to test sidekiq with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, sidekiq

I have a method which kicks off two different Sidekiq workers - one to send an email and one to publish to a Faye channel to the front-end. I am trying to test the behaviour in a Cucumber feature. The code works fine in development.

I have included `require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'` in `features/support/env.rb`, so that I can check the actual results of the workers efforts. The test for the email works fine (using Spreewald email steps), but I can't see any evidence that the other worker has been executed. I have included 'logger.debug' statements in the worker but they do not appear in the `log/test.log` - is there somewhere else I should look?

It seems unlikely that the worker is not running, but the front-end doesn't appear to receive the Faye message. Any suggestions on how to debug it would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to run my Sidekiq workers in my cucumber test by adding the appropriate require statement in `support/env.rb`:

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
```

If using Spork, put it in your prefork block:

```
Spork.prefork do
  # ...
  require 'sidekiq/testing'
  # ...
```

Then I wrote a feature that read something like this:

```
When I submit the form that adds jobs to the queue
Then I should see "Your jobs were added to the queue."
When I wait for the jobs to finish
And I refresh the page
Then the completed jobs are listed on the page
```

Then I manually drain the queue:

```
When(/^I wait for the jobs to finish$/) do
  MySpecialWorker.drain
end
```

You may also be able to make all your jobs run inline by adding `Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` to your `support/env.rb` after the require statement, but since I only wanted to run these jobs, I chose to manually run only the ones I cared about.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, we need the test for any test cases with `Sidekiq::Testing.fake!` mode. 
In our project, we have already used RSpec hook method to make it. Follow the below code, you can see:
in the file `features/support/capybara.rb`

```
Around('@sidekiq_job') do |_scenario, block|
  Sidekiq::Testing.fake! do
    block.call
  end
end
```

And this is an example with this config:

```
@sidekiq_job
Scenario: Your scenario
Given ...
And ...
When ...
Then the demo should be enqueued
```

And

```
Then /^the demo employee should be enqueued$/ do
  expect(YourWorker.jobs.size).to eq(1)
end
```